# Pseudo-effective divisor which is not nef in any birational model

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry, minimal-model-program, analytic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective algebraic variety and let $D$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier pseudo-effective divisor on $X$. Lets say that $D$ is *birationally nef*
if there exists a birational rational map $\pi \colon X \dashrightarrow Y$, with $Y$ a possibly singular projective algebraic variety such that $\pi_*(D)$ is a nef divisor.

$1$. The minimal model program conjectures that if $D=K_X+\Delta$ for a klt pair $(X,\Delta)$ then pseudo-effective implies birationally nef.

$2$. In dimension two it seems that pseudo-effective implies birationally nef as well by Zariski decomposition and Artin contractibility criterion.

$3$. I expect that a pseudo-effective divisor $D$ whose diminished base locus ${\rm Bs}_{-}(D)$ is dense on $X$ may give an example of a pseudo-effective divisor  which is not birationally nef. Since it looks like for any map $\pi \colon X \dashrightarrow Y$ 
the diminished base locus ${\rm Bs}_{-}(\pi_{*}(D))$ will be non-trivial.

I am only aware of one example holding the condition on $3$, and in such case
$D$ pushes-forward to an ample divisor on $\mathbb{P}^3$, so it does not give a counter-example.

Is there a natural family of examples of pseudo-effective divisors which are not birationally nef?

**Remark**: If what I am defining as *birationally nef* is already defined in the literature, please feel free to edit the question.

Comment: What do you mean by $\pi_*$?

Comment: divisorial push-forward

Comment: @ChenJiang: if $U$ is the locus where $\pi$ is defined, then $X\setminus U$ has codimension $\geq 2$. Thus, we get an isomorphism $\operatorname{Cl}(X) \stackrel\sim\to \operatorname{Cl}(U)$. Define $\pi_*$ as the pushforward along $U \to Y$, in the sense of codimension $1$ cycles (see e.g. Fulton's *Intersection Theory*, $\S1.4$). Since $X$ is smooth, you don't need to worry about Weil vs. Cartier divisors, but it seems that $\pi_* D$ is a priori only a $\mathbb Q$-Weil divisor on $Y$.

Comment: Are you sure about condition $3$?  If your example is what I suspect, you can just push the divisor forward via the blow-down to $\mathbb P^3$ and the pushforward class is $\mathcal O(1)$.  On the other hand, there are probably similar examples on CY3's for which $B_{-}(D)$ is not closed and there are no contractions possible.

Comment: @Mark Yes, you are right, that example does not give a counter-example, I will clarify this in the question itself. 

May you elaborate a little more about those similar examples with CY3's?